# How mock an object created from a static method with a Mocked objet as param in Jest

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I wrote a Nestjs sample project,  The project source codes: https://github.com/hantsy/nestjs-graphql-sample and tried to test a custom permissions guard.

```js
@Injectable()
export class HasPermissionsGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const routePermissions = this.reflector.get<PermissionType[]>(
      HAS_PERMISSIONS_KEY,
      context.getHandler(),
    );
    if (!routePermissions || routePermissions.length == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    const { user } = GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext()
      .req as AuthenticatedRequest;
    return (
      user.permissions &&
      user.permissions.some((r) => routePermissions.includes(r))
    );
  }
}
```

When I tried to use Jest to test the logic of `HasPermissionsGuard`,

```js
  it('should return true if the `HasPermissions` decorator is set', async () => {
    const context = mock<ExecutionContext>();
    context.getHandler.mockReturnValue({} as any);

    // the following will failed. 
    const host = mock<ExecutionContextHost>();
    host.getArgByIndex.mockImplementation((idx: number) => {
      return {
        req: { user: { permissions: [PermissionType.WRITE_POSTS] } as any },
      } as any;
    });

    const ctx = mock<GqlExecutionContext>();
    ctx.getContext.mockReturnValue({
      req: { user: { permissions: [PermissionType.WRITE_POSTS] } as any },
    });

    reflecter.get
      .mockReturnValue([PermissionType.WRITE_POSTS])
      .calledWith(HAS_PERMISSIONS_KEY, context.getHandler());

    const result = await guard.canActivate(context);

    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
    expect(reflecter.get).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

I used `jest-mock-extended` and `jest`,  how to mock `GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved it myself. Create a mocked function and assign it to the `create` static method.

```js
    const mockedCreate = jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementation((ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
        return {
          getContext: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            req: {
              user: { permissions: [PermissionType.WRITE_POSTS] } as any,
            } as any,
          }),
        } as any;
      });
    GqlExecutionContext.create = mockedCreate;
```